# Regex: select all groups of two (hashtag) words next to each other

Tags: python, regex

I've got an example string:

```
#water #atlantic ocean #sea
```

and I want to use regex to select all groups of two hashtag words next to each other. which would return:

```
[[['#water']['#atlantic ocean']], [['#atlantic ocean']['#sea']]]
```

I'm at a loss as to how to do this regex. The closest I've gotten is:
([#][A-Za-z\s]+\s?)

which just yields the following (in python):

```
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'#water ', u'#atlantic ocean ', u'#sea']
```

I've tried putting a {2} at the end but that seems to not match pairs. Any ideas at all on how to achieve this?

Comment: What if there are four tags?

Comment: What does it mean for "two (hashtag) words" to be  "next to each other"?  For example, it looks to me like `#atlantic` and `#sea` are _not_ next to each other.  They are separated by  the non-hashtag word `ocean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(#[^#]*)(?=[^#]*(#[^#]*))
```

Try this.This will give the required groups.Grab the captures.

```
x="#water #atlantic ocean #sea"
print re.findall(r"(#[^#]*)(?=[^#]*(#[^#]*))",x)
```

Output:`[('#water', '#atlantic ocean'), ('#atlantic ocean', '#sea')]`

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/36

Comment: You got `#atlantic` but OP wants `#atlantic ocean`

Comment: Uh.. your code and your demo don't match. Your code actually doesn't give `ocean`.

Comment: it worked when I tried it actually... 

x="#water #atlantic ocean #sea"
print re.findall(r"(#[^#]*)(?=[^#]*(#[^#]*))",x)
[('#water ', '#atlantic ocean '), ('#atlantic ocean ', '#sea')]

it also works well for expansion as I mentioned above.

Comment: This one actually works best for what I'm trying to do because it does return the tuples and I don't have to do the extra split which is why I've chosen it.

Answer (score 2):

To me it feels more intuitive to split on `#` (or space followed by hash) than to use complicated regex:

```
import re
expr = "#water #atlantic ocean #sea"
groups = filter(None, re.split(r' ?#', expr))
# another option is to use a split that doesn't require regex at all:
# groups = filter(None, map(str.strip, expr.split("#"))) 
res = []
for i, itm in enumerate(groups):
    if i < len(groups)-1:
        res.append(["#"+itm, "#"+groups[i + 1]])

print res  # [['#water', '#atlantic ocean'], ['#atlantic ocean', '#sea']]
```

Comment: What if the hashtags also included @ symbols or another type? can you split on multiple characters?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in-order to do a overlapping match.

```
(?=(#[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)?\s#[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)?))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rA1tS5/1)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "#water #atlantic ocean #sea"
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?=(#[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)?\s#[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)?))', s)
>>> print m
['#water #atlantic ocean', '#atlantic ocean #sea']
```

OR

```
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?=(#[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)?)\s(#[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)?))', s)
>>> print m
[('#water', '#atlantic ocean'), ('#atlantic ocean', '#sea')]
```

Use `*` instead of `?` after the non-capturing groups, if the following words would occur zero or more times.

```
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?=(#[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)*)\s(#[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)*))', s)
>>> print m
[('#water', '#atlantic ocean'), ('#atlantic ocean', '#sea')]
```

Comment: This works best for what I'm trying to do I think, because I can expand it to multiple options such as @s if I need... thank you!